# How can I trigger a keyup event and pass the key?

Tags: jquery, bdd

I have a field that "corrects" itself as you type. We have some code written that prevents this functionality when the arrow keys are pressed:

```
handleKeyUp: function(e) {
    var arrowKeys = _.range(37, 41),
        key = e.which;

    // allow user to move cursor by keyboard
    if ($.inArray(key, arrowKeys) < 0) {
        this.removeInvalidCharacters();
    }
},
```

We would like to write a unit test for this; however, we can't figure out how to pass `e.which` via `$input.trigger('keyup')`. I know the second parameter of trigger allows us to send "extra options"; however, that just passes values more values to the `handleKeyUp` function. Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this -

```
var e = $.Event("keyup");
e.which = 37; 
$input.trigger(e);
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

> As of jQuery 1.6, you can also pass an object to jQuery.Event() and
>   its properties will be set on the newly created Event object.

```
// Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 64 });

// trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 64
jQuery("body").trigger( e );
```

Comment: This answer is great, I didn't know you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would allow `handleKeyUp` to accept either an event object or an integer. Just add an extra line for defining what `key` is, depending upon the type of `e`. Then your unit test can run `handleKeyUp(40)`. This is assuming, of course, that the purpose of your unit test isn't to test the `keyup` handlers on the inputs.